# How to update Azure Storage Table one specific property values using other property value in where condition?

Tags: c#, azure, nosql, azure-storage

Let's consider I have the following table storage table NAMED Tbl_ResourceCost.

[image]

Now, I want to update Extended cost by using partition key and ResourceGuID. So, if I pass xxx01 as PartitionKey & zzz01 as ResourceGuID in WHERE condition, then it will update **only** my extendedCost of (i.e. **100 & 200**) to let's say 700.

If we consider it in SQL to update, then the query would be, "UPDATE Tbl_ResourceCost set ExtendedCost=700 where PartitionKey=xxx01 and ResourceGuID=zzz01". It will update both 100 & 200 to 700 in a single execution.

**I am looking for similar query in C# to update in Azure Storage Table**. I am using the NuGet Package as : Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table

Comment: Do you have any update?

Comment: Thanks Jim Xu. The link you provided before on comment section helped me to do the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the Azure table storage entity's properties, we need to provide partition key and row key. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/merge-entity). So according to your need, we need to query Azure table storage to get these your need entities then update these.

For example

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
namespace Storage
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            string connectionString = "";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            var table =tableClient.GetTableReference("test");

            TableQuery<MyEntity> myQuery = new TableQuery<MyEntity>().Where(
                    TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, ""),
                        TableOperators.And,
                    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("ResourceGuID", QueryComparisons.Equal,"")));

            foreach (MyEntity entity in table.ExecuteQuery(myQuery))
            {
                entity.ExtendedCost = ;
                TableOperation insertOrMergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(entity);
                TableResult result = await table.ExecuteAsync(insertOrMergeOperation);
                var s = result.Result as MyEntity;
               Console.WriteLine(s.ExtendedCost )
            }

        }      
    }

    public class MyEntity : TableEntity
    {
        public MyEntity()
        {
        }

  
        public string ResourceGuID{ get; set; }

        public Int32 ExtendedCost { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. It helped me. I was looking for exactly same.